# new gatsby project is not running

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've created new gatsby project. After successful installation, I tried to run it with command `npm run develop` and `gatsby develop` but it is throwing error. Unable to figure out the root cause of error. I tried re installing node_modules but nothing is working! Please Help! Thank you!

**ERROR:**

```
D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site>npm run develop

> test-site@1.0.0 develop
> gatsby develop

D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\artifacts\index.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1185:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\index.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\dist\node.js:14:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "test-site",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`,
    },
    plugins: [

    ]
}
```

*PLEASE HELP!!!*

Comment: Which node version are you using? You can find it with command `node -v`

Comment: Its Node v16.14.0

Comment: did you run `npm install`? that will help to install essential packages

Comment: Yes I've already tried but still error!!!

Comment: Could you share the repository, where you clone from, with me? I can help to check it locally.

Comment: I've simply created new gatsby project with 'npm init gatsby' command. It is giving error!

Comment: Please try installing npm init gatsby in your end. If it will run successfully please share the version numbers or code directly.

Comment: Where (in what folder) have you run `npm install`?

Comment: In D drive and inside FC folder

Comment: Which site did you select during installation? Shopify?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by adding a library of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistribution on my computer as the package is failing due to a missing library.

The download link is here: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

It took a lot of time for mine to solve. Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Where (in what folder) have you run npm install?

> In D drive and inside FC folder

You must install your dependencies inside your project folder, so inside `gatsby-shopify-site`. In your case, you installed your dependencies in the parent folder (FC),

Move inside `D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site` and run:

```
npm install
```

Once done:

```
gatsby develop
```

Comment: I've done the same process but still not working!

Comment: Run `gatsby clean` and then `gatsby develop` again

Comment: Already tried still not working. Same Error! :(

Comment: Does the `npm install` output any warning or error message?

Comment: D:\FC\test-site>npm install

up to date, audited 1478 packages in 14s

208 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

19 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 13 high)

Comment: Well, you changed the site folder now... Remove the `node_modules` and try a fresh install

Comment: Already tried but still getting error!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the right node js version for your Windows system.
As mentioned in the error, it is trying to execute a win32-x64 version. In my case Node website recommended the wrong version when downloading and this was fixed by changing it.

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\D:\FC\gatsby-shopify-site\node_modules\@parcel\source-map\parcel_sourcemap_node\artifacts\index.win32-x64-msvc.node
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Could you try `yarn` instead?

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and then run your command like this

```
yarn run develop
```

Comment: @Toshita the problem is still happening with your setup?